# Unexpected GET values with different URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

The idea is to pass a SMB file URL or a normal website URL as GET parameter to a Spring web MVC controller. However there are some issues with the correct output:

GET values:

- http://localhost:8080/docapp/document/test/42 --> GET value: 42
- http://localhost:8080/docapp/document/test/www.google.com --> GET value: www.google
- http://localhost:8080/docapp/document/test/www.google.com/ --> GET value: www.google.com
- http://localhost:8080/docapp/document/test/%5C%5Csmbserver%5Caccounts%5Ctestaccount%5CWas_muessen_Programme_verarbeiten.docx --> Blank page, no exceptions

As you can see the second and fourth URL examples do not work, so my question:

- How can I handle the second example? The correct output should be www.google.com.
- What happens during the fourth example?

Setup information: An Ubuntu 14.04 LTS x64 and Tomcat 8 are used

Java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/document/test/{url}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String test(@PathVariable String url, Model model) throws IOException
{
    model.addAttribute("url",  url);
    return "test";
}
```

HTML

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Value: ${url}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: instead of pathVariable. get url using request object

Comment: Try to URL encode twice or thrice and pass it to the URL and at the server side Just fully decode the URL

Answer (score 0):

Change the request mapping as below:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/document/test/{url:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

And the 4th URL is not working as you need to encode `%`. Please find below the encoded URL:

http://localhost:8080/gradle-spring-mvc-web-project/document/test/%255C%255Csmbserver%255Caccounts%255Ctestaccount%255CWas_muessen_Programme_verarbeiten.docx